# RN spyOn click Method is not an assignable parameter of type context setState etc

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, enzyme

Using RN 16.9.0 with Jest. I am trying to spyOn a button from my Component, but always getting an error.

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "handleClick");
```

handeClick is red underlined and shows following error (also when running jest test):

> Argument of type '"handleClick"' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type '"context" | "setState" | "forceUpdate" | "render" |
>   "componentDidMount" | "shouldComponentUpdate" | "componentWillUnmount"
>   | "componentDidCatch" | "getSnapshotBeforeUpdate" | ... 6 more ... |
>   "UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate"'

My Component looks like this:

```
export default class RecordTimer extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {...}
  ...
  render() {
     return (
        <Button
          onPress={this.handleClick}
          ...
        />
  )
}
```

Comment: Any luck finding what it was? I found that if I first store my wrapper.instance() in a variable and then call jest.spyOn(myVariable, 'someFunction'); I get past the type check, but then I get: object[methodName].mockImplementation is not a function.

Comment: Any btw. the variable trick only works because I declared it as type any. Another way would be just doing this: jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance() as any, "handleClick");